# dropdown navigation issues

Tags: jquery, css, navigation

I am having issues with the positioning of the child elements of my dropdown menu, please hover over the services tab to see what's happening.

i want them to display at the bottom of the parent element...

i had created this as a non drop down originally, and my client wants to add dropdowns, so i was trying to integrate a simple one to maintain the style...

it works the same across all browser and is using jquery...

http://www.suzetteballew.com/kdadev/index.html

thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please post simplified, relevant code samples for us to work with.

Answer (score 1):

give the parent li

```
position:relative
```

then give the drop-down ul

```
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0
```

EDIT: not sure why you need jQuery for this? It's quite achievable with :hover pseudo selector

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need to get rid of your

```
overflow: hidden;
```

on your header section for it to show and not drop behind your gallery